# Linq & SQL: Counting the number of people living in a place per year with only the start and end dates of their residencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Currently I have a table in SQL of people with the start date and end date of their residencies. I would like to be able to find the number of people living in that place for each year in a list of years.

i.e.

```
Person, Start, End

A, 2013, 2014

B, 2013, 2015

C, 2014, 2015
```

Should give me something like:

```
2012, 0


2013, 2


2014, 3

2015, 2
```

My issue is that I don't have the list of years stored anywhere in SQL. I would have to somehow generate this list of years in SQL... I have this list of years in memory, but I can't do joins with data in memory without loading my whole table into memory... I can't figure out a way to get my list of years server-side so that I can do this query... Once it's there though, I'm pretty sure all I have to do is some sort of left outer join and then group by the year and select the sum... but I can't get to there until I figure out some way to generate all of these years.

Comment: Depending on the version of sql-server you are using, you could look into APPLY and CROSS APPLY to generate those rows for each year. You may also need a table of years to join. This table will have the min and max years of your dataset. If the data is not too big, you can get away with writing simple functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your Linq tag, then you can also use some Linq To Objects. In which case, you can use Linq-To-Sql to get a summary of the people, eg

```
var grouped = (from r in Person
    group r by new { r.Start, r.End } into results
    select new { results.Key.Start, results.Key.End, count = results.Count()}
    ).ToList();
```

Then switch to Linq To objects to find the first and last year

```
var firstYear = grouped.Min(a=>a.Start) ?? 0;
var lastYear  = grouped.Max(a=>a.End) ?? 0;
```

And then iterate through all the years to find the total number of people, eg something like

```
List<object> yearlySummary = new List<object>();

for (int year = firstYear; year <= lastYear; year++)
{
     var no = (from r in grouped where r.Start <= year && r.End >= year select (int?) r.count).Sum() ?? 0;

     yearlySummary.Add(new { year, no} );   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this in one query unless you have another table that contains the years you want to display.

---

### Simple solution (2 queries + 1 per year)

One option is to get the min and max dates using 1 query each and then looping through the dates to get your information using 1 query per year

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    var combinedQuery = db.Dates.Select(d => d.start).Union(db.Dates.Select(d => d.end));
    int min = combinedQuery.Min();
    int max = combinedQuery.Max();

    for (int year = min - 1; year <= max; year++)
    {
        var count = db.Dates.Count(x => year >= x.start && year <= x.end);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", year, count);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

### Not as simple (2 queries)

Alternatively you could retrieve the min and max date using one query, taking advantage of using two subselects.

Now that you have the min and max dates, you can loop through them to generate your Year query (this will act as your pseudo Year table that you do not have). This is done by unioning each year together and then using a subselect to get the count.

```
using (var db = new Context())
{    
    var combinedQuery = db.Dates.Select(d => d.start).Union(db.Dates.Select(d => d.end));
    var minAndMax = db.tests.Select(x => new 
                    { 
                       Min = combinedQuery.Min(), 
                       Max = combinedQuery.Max() 
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
    int min = minAndMax.Min;
    int max = minAndMax.Max;

    IQueryable<int> yearQuery = null;

    for (int year = min - 1; year <= max; year++)
    {
        int tempYear = year;
        var query = db.tests.Take(1).Select(x => tempYear);

        if (yearQuery == null)
        {
            yearQuery = query;
        }
        else
        {
            yearQuery = yearQuery.Concat(query);
        }
    }

    var results = (from year in yearQuery
                   select new
                   {
                       Year = year,
                       Count = db.Dates.Count(x => year >= x.start && year <= x.end),
                   }).ToList();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

- Note `linq-to-entities` and `linq-to-sql` act a little differently, the queries generated were using `linq-to-entities`.